# How to connect these 2 pipes?

Tags: mesh

how can I connect this round pipe to the oval pipe?

Or how can I make a tube that is round on one side and oval on the other and then bend 90 degrees?[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: hello, probably with Ctrl E > Bridge Edge Loops but please link an image so that we can see a screenshot

Comment: ok but use an image host website  ;)  or even share your file (upload and copy paste the URL): https://pasteall.org/blend/ weird that you can't post an image though

Comment: See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: I have often asked questions here with photos, put my text (question) then click on the place photo icon and then drag my photo to the box and place my question.
If I do that now, it says that the body is not there.

Comment: The CTRL E works, but if you now make 1 tube rectangular it won't work anymore

Comment: give your rectangular pipe as many vertices as your cylinder

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: manually, if for example box has 4 vertices and cylinder has 16 vertices then you need manually with Ctrl+R add 12 more vertices to the box... for future you, if you plan to connect multiple pieces together, try to always set same number of vertices... if you plan to connect two cylinders, make sure you make them with same amount of vertices

Comment: I still can't make the tube, wall thickness 2 mm.
On one side it is round 60 mm and on the other side rectangular 40 x 20 mm (outside dimensions).
It should also be bent at a 90 degree angle.
See drawing.
I've tried almost "everything", but I can't seem to find the one right way.
It is for a fan that must extract the air and can be 3D printed (STL).
Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I did it, it was because I made the rectangle using "solidify". Now I made the rectangle with 1 rectangle in the correct outer dimensions and 1 rectangle that is 4 mm smaller, I "slid" the small rectangle into the large rectangle and "join" these 2 rectangles.